# How To Parse CSV Data into XCode for App UI

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, csv

I have been following this guide to help me parse the CSV data I have into XCode so I can put it into an app: https://makeapppie.com/2016/05/23/reading-and-writing-text-and-csv-files-in-swift/

This guide is a little outdated and I got too many errors once I tried to load my CSV. I was wondering if there is an updated method to get CSV data into XCode for an app?
Here's an example of the data I want to place into my UI:
[My CSV Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMxD6.png)

Thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting? What have you done to try and correct those errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try this . Might help

```
func csv(data: String) -> [[String]] {
    var result: [[String]] = []
    let rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    for row in rows {
        let columns = row.components(separatedBy: "\t")
        result.append(columns)
    }
    return result
}
```

Then you can access any value via:

```
var data = readDataFromCSV(fileName: FileName, fileType:FileExtension)
data = cleanRows(file: data)
let csvRows = csv(data: data)
print(csvRows[1][1])
```